# Support backtick code in titles

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, questions, design, title

Can we have back tick code in titles that render in the questions list and the post page? It would be nice to have the fixed width font for actual code snips in a title.

Comment: titles are also used outside of SO, for example on Google. How does it have impact there?

Comment: @rene in the window title bar and search results ie `<title>` tag can be rendered with backticks.

Comment: I don't fancy  them simply being rendered. Maybe here in the context of SO it could be tolerated but on Google I don't think seeing ` printf( i++ + ++i); ` would be an awesome experience, as much as I hate the results with [Solved] and other markup noise.

Comment: I can't think of a single code-including title that couldn't be simply made better by explaining the problem at hand rather than showing the example of what's going on. I don't see any reason for titles to include code in the first place, let alone provide markdown for them.

Comment: I think this is worth re-evaluating. GitHub recently started [supporting `code` in titles](https://github.blog/changelog/2021-04-13-back-tick-code-blocks-are-now-supported-in-titles/). And I don't think more formatting should be allowed in contrast to the duplicate question.

Answer (score 16):

Titles should be descriptive of the problem being attempted to solve.  They don't require much in the way of fancy styling or emphasis; they require *clarity* into the actual problem.  Adding formatting - like backticks - does nothing to motivate the goal of making the question any clearer.

Comment: i disagree, it could make the readability of the titles better to indicate code.

Comment: @DanielA.White:  Yes, but what good is indicating code in a title if you're explicitly asking *about* code?  Why would backticks make one's question clearer if they're asking about code?

Comment: @DanielA.White: If a title is not clear *without* the formatting, then it's a bad title.

Comment: I disagree. When you need to refer e.g. class name in the title, having it in different style would improve readability / make it more understandable. After saying that, I have to agree with BSMP that some people would use backticks for `emphasis` so allowing backticks to change formatting in titles may not be worth the trouble.

Comment: @MikkoRantalainen:  If you can't discern from context that what the title is about is a class or method, then the title is unclear and formatting wouldn't save it.

Comment: Given the ubiquity of Markdown nowadays, backticks DO actually help me visually scan text to find code (or code snippets)!

Comment: Let's not forget accessibility tools such as screen readers. Titles with the `<code>`-HTML tag could actually improve accessibility and SEO.